# Proof check: the rows of the matrix $E$ of elementary operations that correspond to the zero rows of the echelon form $U$ are a basis for $N(A^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix with rank $r$. Let $U$ denote the non-reduced echelon form. Let $E$ be the composite of elementary matrices such that $EA = U$. Prove that the rows of $E$ that correspond to the zero rows of $U$ give a basis for the null space of $A^T$.

I had no problem with the linear independence proof, but the spanning proof gave me a harder time. Could someone please proof check me?

**Proof of spanning.** Let $\vec x$ be s.t. $A^T\vec x = 0$. Then, $\vec x^TA = 0$. Notice that $x^TA$ is in the row space of $A$. Since elementary row operations are simply linear combinations, we know the row space of $A$ is the same as the row space of $U$, so we can write $$\vec x^T A = x_1U_1 + \cdots + x_nU_n=0$$.

Recall that the rank of $A$ is $r$, and we know it is a theorem that $U_1, \cdots, U_r$ form a basis for the row space, therefore, using the linear independence of this basis, we know $x_1 = \cdots = x_r = 0$, and $$\vec x^T A = x_{r+1}U_{r+n} + \cdots + x_nU_{r+n}$$

But by definition, $U_i = E_iA$, therefore, $$\vec x^T A = x_{r+1}E_{r+1}A + \cdots +x_nE_nA$$

$$\vec x^T A = (x_{r+1}E_{r+1} + \cdots +x_nE_n)A$$

From which we conclude that $\vec x$ is a linear combination of $E_{r+1}, \dots, E_{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof only works if $A$ has a right inverse (you need to multiply by such a right inverse to cancel $A$ in your last equation).

For a general proof, I'm partial to the kind of dimension counting proof found here [Why do row vectors of the matrix $E$ s.t. $EA$ is the echelon form of $A$ serve as a basis for the left null space of $A$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4250162/why-do-row-vectors-of-the-matrix-e-s-t-ea-is-the-echelon-form-of-a-serve) (so I won't repeat it here).

If you want to try it for yourself, a strong hint is to first show that multiplying by elementary matrices does not change the dimension of the row space or nullspace (which follows by invertibility), and then try to calculate what the dimension of the left nullspace must be.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be awarding the bounty when the minimum time is over